# how to edit a json file using python

Tags: python, json

First of all take a look at my json structure

```
{
    "some_id": [
        {
            "embed": False,
            "plain_msg": "Some text",
            "embed_text": [
                {
                    "title": "any title",
                    "body": "any bpdy text",
                    "color": "random color"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Lets say I have a json file as **filename.json** with the given json.
Now I want to change value of **embed** without changing any other data.

I have a simple code

```
  with open('filename.json', 'r') as f:
      json_data = json.load(f)
  json_data['some_id'] = 'Some string'
    with open('filename.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(json_data, f, indent=2)
```

But this code can only write inside **some_id** and rewrite all value with the given string as

```
{
    "some_id": "Some string"
}
```

Please help me how can I do this!
I need your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution after a lot testing and searching.

The correct code is

```
with open('filename.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

json_data['some_id'][0]['embed'] = 'Some string'
with open('filename.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f, indent=2)
```

It neither duplicate any data nor delete any existing data just change.
OMG I got it finally.

Answer (score 4):

`json_data` becomes a dictionary with the same structure as your JSON.  To access 'inner' elements, you just have to navigate the dictionary structure.

See comment below.

```py
  with open('filename.json', 'r') as f:
      json_data = json.load(f)
  json_data['some_id'][0]['embed'] = 'Some string' # On this line you needed to add ['embed'][0]
    with open('filename.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(json_data, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: This is returning this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p:\Web Hosting\ServerX\public\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    json_data['test_id']['embed'] = 'Some string' # On this line you needed to add ['embed']
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Then, I think you must be wrong about the structure of your JSON.  Possibly you have JSON embedded in a string.  In that case you would need:   json_loads(json_data['some_id'])['embed'] = 'Some string'

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you want to edit the value on the file you already have ('filename.json'), and not create a new file with that one field edited.

In that case, you don't need the nested `with open...` structure.
Also, notice you have to fully index the field you are trying to edit in the dictionary returned by the json.load() method. It will be under "some_id", but that key holds a list with one element, so then you need to refer to index0. Finally, the element on index0 is also a dictionary where the "embed" keys exist - and that's what you want to change.

Try this:

```
    with open('filename.json', 'r+') as f:
      json_data = json.load(f)
      json_data['some_id'][0]['embed'] = 'Some string'
      json.dump(json_data, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: This code duplicating the whole json and disturbing the structure

Comment: I edited my commend to account for the fact that "embed" is actually in a dictionary that resides in a list.